# Preimage and Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I apologize if this seems trivial, would still appreciate help.

Let

• $X=\underset{\alpha\in I}{\prod}X_{\alpha}$
  be the cartesian product of sets $\left\{ X_{\alpha}\right\} _{\alpha\in I}$
 .

• $U=\underset{\alpha\in I}{\prod}U_{\alpha}$
  s.t $\forall\alpha\in I$
 : $U_{\alpha}\subseteq X_{\alpha}$
 .

• $\pi_{\beta}:X\to X_{\beta}
 , \left(x_{\alpha}\right)_{\alpha\in I}\mapsto x_{\beta}$
  be projection from $X$
  to $X_{\beta}$ for $\beta\in I$
 .

I want to show that $U=\underset{\alpha\in I}{\bigcap}\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}\left(\pi_{\alpha}\left(U\right)\right)$
 :

• $\subseteq$: Let $u\in U$
  and $\alpha\in I$
 . By image definition $\pi_{\alpha}\left(u\right)\in\pi_{\alpha}\left(U\right)$.
  $u$
  is an input of $\pi_{\alpha}\left(u\right)$
 , therefore by preimage definition $u\in\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}\left(\pi_{\alpha}\left(U\right)\right)$
 .(I hope this direction is fine)

• $\supseteq$: This is the part I have a problem with. Would appreciate direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of $U \subseteq \bigcap_\alpha \pi_\alpha^{-1}\bigl[\pi_\alpha[U]\bigr]$ is fine.

For the other direction: Suppose that $x \in  \bigcap_\alpha \pi_\alpha^{-1}\bigl[\pi_\alpha[U]\bigr]$, then for each $\alpha$ we have $x \in  \pi_\alpha^{-1}\bigl[\pi_\alpha[U]\bigr]$, that is, by definition of the preimage, $\pi_\alpha(x) \in \pi_\alpha[U]$. Now, by definition of $U$, we have $\pi_\alpha[U] = U_\alpha$, hence $x_\alpha \in U_\alpha$ for every $\alpha$. Therefore, $x \in U$.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Thanks a lot!